# ¿Usar una columna creada en un case when en otro case when? SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Cómo puedo usar una columna creada mediante un sentencia `case when` en otra columna que pasará por una sentencia `case when`.

Por ejemplo, si creo las columnas `c_creada1` y `c_creada2` y las quiero usar para crear una nueva columna me indica que `El nombre de columna 'c_creada1' no es válido`.

```
select 'c_creada1' = case 
    when var1 = 1 then 12
    else 20
    end,
    'c_creada2' = case 
    when var2 = 1 then 12
    else 20
    end,
    'c_creada3' = case 
    when c_creada1 = 12 and c_creada2 = 12 then 12
    else null
    end,
* from dbo.tabla1
```

¿Por qué sucede esto?
¿Cómo podría resolver el problema?

Comment: Porque estás expresando `'v_creada_1'` como nombre de columna en tabla1. Si le indicas `@v_creada_1`, va a usar la variable.

Comment: Perdón, escribí mal. `v_creada_1` y `v_creada_2 ` son columnas.

Comment: Saludos. Las variable deben iniciar con `@` y su alcance esta limitado a donde son declaradas hacia adentro (no hacia afuera). Te sugiero crear una función o dos según se requiere de tipo determinística (que resuelve más rápido ejemplo en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651662/sql-server-deterministic-user-defined-function). Ya leí la respuesta a la propuesta de `WITH` (abajo) y lo que pongo creo es más adecuado a tu caso.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar una cte o una tabla derivada para acceder a las columnas creadas en la select. Esto se debe al orden de procesamiento.

```
With cte as (
select 'v_creada1' = case 
    when var1 = 1 then 12
    else 20
    end,
    'v_creada2' = case 
    when var2 = 1 then 12
    else 20
    end
* 
from dbo.tabla1
)
Select * 
, 'v_creada3' = case 
    when v_creada1 = 12 and v_creada2 = 12 then 12
    else null
    end
from cte
```

Otra opción es hacerlo como una tabla derivada

```
Select *,
, 'v_creada3' = case 
    when v_creada1 = 12 and v_creada2 = 12 then 12
    else null
    end
from 
(
select 'v_creada1' = case 
    when var1 = 1 then 12
    else 20
    end,
    'v_creada2' = case 
    when var2 = 1 then 12
    else 20
    end
* 
from dbo.tabla1
) as data
```

Comment: ¿No hay una forma más sencilla?

Comment: @césarhuamanininahuanca es una forma bastante sencilla, considerando cómo habría sido en versiones anteriores...

Comment: o volver a poner cada expresión case completa en sustitucion de `v_creada1`. Porque puedes perfectamente volver a emplear la misma expresión case, en su lugar.

Comment: Mis condicionales son muy largaa por eso primero creaba columnas.

Comment: Puedes crear una función escalar que retorne el resultado de tús condiciones, ante una serie de parámetros, para hacer más fácil esta legibilidad, pero puede tener su impacto en rendimiento.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que las columnas creadas como expresiones dentro de una consulta no pueden hacer referencia a otra expresión en la misma lista de columnas. Para eso hay opciones distintas. Puedes usar el operador APPLY para generar expresiones que no dependan de múltiples filas:

```
SELECT ca.v_creada1,
       ca.v_creada2,
       v_creada3 = CASE WHEN ca.v_creada1 = 12 and ca.v_creada2 = 12 THEN 12 ELSE NULL END,
       t.* 
FROM dbo.tabla1 t
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT v_creada1 = CASE WHEN t.var1 = 1 THEN 12 ELSE 20 END,
                     v_creada2 = CASE WHEN t.var2 = 1 THEN 12 ELSE 20 END) ca;
```

En tu caso, podrías usar las condiciones de las expresiones anteriores.

```
SELECT v_creada1 = CASE WHEN t.var1 = 1 THEN 12 ELSE 20 END,
       v_creada2 = CASE WHEN t.var2 = 1 THEN 12 ELSE 20 END,
       v_creada3 = CASE WHEN t.var1 = 1 and t.var2 = 1 = 12 THEN 12 ELSE NULL END,
       t.* 
FROM dbo.tabla1 t
```

O puedes usar una subconsulta o CTE para generar las columnas y luego hacer expresiones con ellas.

```
WITH cteTabla1 AS(
    SELECT v_creada1 = CASE WHEN t.var1 = 1 THEN 12 ELSE 20 END,
           v_creada2 = CASE WHEN t.var2 = 1 THEN 12 ELSE 20 END,
           t.* 
    FROM dbo.tabla1 t
)
SELECT *,
       v_creada3 = CASE WHEN v_creada1 = 12 and v_creada2 = 12 THEN 12 ELSE NULL END
FROM cteTabla1;
```

Sin embargo, este último método puede llegar a repetir mucho código cuando la lista de columnas es extensa.